# MySQL query returning error message

Tags: mysql, while-loop

I have following query which push id into temp table and delete records from another table by joining with temp table.
I am using limit to optimize log file flushes.

```
SET @StartDate='2012-12-26';
SET @EndDate='2014-01-11';

INSERT INTO temp_A
SELECT id FROM A
WHERE created > @StartDate  AND created < @EndDate
ORDER BY created;

SET @recordNotFound =0;

WHILE(@recordNotFound = 0)
BEGIN
DELETE 
FROM B
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT t2.id
       FROM temp_A AS t2
       WHERE t2.id = B.txn_id
) 
ORDER BY txn_id DESC
LIMIT 1000;

IF (ROW_COUNT() <> 1000) THEN
SET @recordNotFound=1;
END IF;
END
END WHILE;
```

I am getting syntax error here.
Can someone please help, what is going wrong here?

Comment: If you include the actual syntax error it will make things easier for you and for future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need an actual error message to be able to help you, though from what you posted we can see one thing for sure - there's missing ';' after END before END WHILE;

Comment: Thanks guys! I created a procedure out of it and it worked. Also corrected syntax of WHILE by adding DO.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in the [manual entry for `while`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/while.html).

```
SET @StartDate='2012-12-26';
SET @EndDate='2014-01-11';

INSERT INTO temp_A
SELECT id FROM A
WHERE created > @StartDate  AND created < @EndDate
ORDER BY created;

SET @recordNotFound =0;

WHILE (@recordNotFound = 0) DO /*you're missing a DO here*/
#BEGIN /*you don't need this*/
DELETE 
FROM B
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT t2.id
       FROM temp_A AS t2
       WHERE t2.id = B.txn_id
) 
ORDER BY txn_id DESC
LIMIT 1000;

IF (ROW_COUNT() <> 1000) THEN
SET @recordNotFound=1;
END IF;
#END /*this line you don't need either*/
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Actually this END has BEGIN - it's on the line right after WHILE.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks. But both lines aren't needed, as can be seen in the manual entry I linked.